# Constructing random divergence-free velocity fields

Tags: fluid-dynamics, randomized-algorithms

I am trying to simulate decaying homogeneous isotropic turbulence. As initial condition I want a divergence-free vector-field, i.e, $\mathrm{div} U = 0$.

How do I initialize random velocity field in an uniform grid such that above condition is satisfied?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! Are you sure you mean $\mathrm{div} U =0$, i.e., that the *sum* of the derivatives vanish? This can obviously happen without the single derivatives being zero.

Comment: Thank you Christian Clason. yes I mean it right, I want to create a set of incompressible initial velocity field such that divU = 0

Comment: OK, such a vector field is called *divergence-free*; I have taken the liberty to edit your question to make that explicit -- I hope you don't mind (otherwise you can revert the edit).

Comment: And googling "random divergence-free" gives a few hits: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/15326349.2012.699756, http://martian-labs.com/martiantoolz/files/DFnoiseR.pdf, http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.611.9001&rep=rep1&type=pdf. Does any of that help?

Comment: It seems that there are two aspects to your question that both Bill Barth and Doug Lipinski address. The first aspect is the purely mathematical one, how to make a initial velocity field divergence free, which Bill points out can be achieved, basically, by using a vector identity. I believe this is similar (or equivalent) to Helmholtz vector decomposition. The second aspect is a physical one, will the divergence-free initial velocity field have characteristics representative of homogeneous isotropic turbulence? Doug points to references on how to address this second aspect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A purely random initial condition will not resemble realistic turbulence and will take quite some time to reach a realistic decay state. If you want good results it's more complicated than just ensuring zero divergence. Usually the velocity field is generated in spectral space to give the proper spectral energy distribution and is then transformed to physical space to initialize the simulation.

Section 4.1 of the following paper outlines one way to do this:
Huidan Yu, Sharath S. Girimaji, Li-Shi Luo, DNS and LES of decaying isotropic turbulence with and without frame rotation using lattice Boltzmann method, Journal of Computational Physics, Volume 209, Issue 2, 1 November 2005, Pages 599-616, ISSN 0021-9991, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jcp.2005.03.022.

This section begins:

> We conduct the simulations in a 3D periodic cube with various resolutions $N^3$. The initial incompressible homogeneous isotropic velocity field $\vec{u}_0$ (${\nabla} \cdot \vec{u}_0 = 0$) is generated in spectral space $\kappa$ with the following energy spectrum in a prescribed range $\kappa_{\min} \le \kappa \le \kappa_{\max}$ and a random phase (cf. details in [47]):
>   \begin{align}
> \hat{E}(\kappa,0) = \left\{
> \begin{array}
> 0.038\kappa^m \exp(-0.14\kappa^2) & \kappa\in[\kappa_{\min},\kappa_{\max}],\\
> 0 & \kappa\notin[\kappa_{\min},\kappa_{\max}].
> \end{array}
> \right.~~~~~~~~~~~~(16)
> \end{align}
>
> Then the velocity field is transferred to physical space.  In what follows, we use $m = 4$ or $2$ in Eq. (16) to investigate the effect of $m$ on the energy spectrum and other quantities.
>
> ...
>
> [47]  T. Miyauchi, T. Ishizu, Direct numerical simulation of homogeneous isotropic turbulence – decay of passive scalar fluctuation, in
>   Preprint vol. JSME No. 914-2, 1991, pp. 166–168.

You might also want to look at:
Consistent initial conditions for the DNS of compressible turbulence
Ristorcelli, J. R. and Blaisdell, G. A., Physics of Fluids, 9, 4-6 (1997), DOI:http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.869152
which could also be used for incompressible turbulence by using only the first step in their procedure which involves generating an appropriate divergence-free velocity field.

That paper chooses a solenoidal (zero divergence) velocity field with spectrum $E(\kappa) = A\kappa^4\exp(-2\kappa^2/\kappa_p^2)$ and random phase components. $A$ determines the velocity amplitude. $\kappa_p$ determines the peak in the spectral energy and is set equal to $12$ in that paper.

Note that these two methods are equivalent with appropriate choices of parameters.

**Edit:**
As for the specifics of generating a zero-divergence velocity with a desired energy spectrum, that question has been asked [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/23159/how-to-obtain-values-in-physical-space-for-a-given-spectrum) but has not been answered. Perhaps someone can go back and answer that old question now.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Doug. This is exactly what I want to do "decaying homogeneous isotropic turbulence". Although the paper states it clearly about the generation of velocity field. I am facing difficulty in how to transfer velocity field from spectral space to physical space.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that it is related to Fast Fourier Transforms but not really sure how it is done exactly. If you can briefly point out how it is done? This would be great help!!

Comment: @verito That question has been asked [here](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/23159/how-to-obtain-values-in-physical-space-for-a-given-spectrum) but not answered. This related question may help you a bit but asks about the other direction (computing the energy spectrum from the velocity field) http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21360/computing-turbulent-energy-spectrum-from-isotropic-turbulence-flow-field-in-a-bo

Comment: The second paper I linked also has some details, including the fact that the Fourier components of the velocity field must be aligned with the wave vector $\vec{\kappa}$ for the field to be divergence-free.

Answer (score 14):

Create two random scalar fields $f$ and $g$ and set the velocity to: 
$$
u=\nabla f \times \nabla g
$$
which is guaranteed to be divergence free.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in 2D and if you want more physical setups, I suggest you consider [*potential flows*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_flow).

There are various ways to construct these *potential flows* which are always divergence free and which satisfy certain boundary conditions.

In the wikipedia article, you find the [*power laws*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_flow#Power_laws), that describes flows around plates, edges, or in corners.

Also, there are other generating functions, that may give you, e.g., the flow around an idealized airfoil.

Comment: Thank you Jan. I am in 3D and looking for DNS simulation of DHIT as Doug Lipinski has pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create any divergence-free field, you can take it to the Fourier space and kill its divergence by subtracting its projection along with $k$ vectors.

$$F_{\text{divFree}}(k)=F(k) - (F(k)\cdot\vec{k}) \hat{k}$$

Just come back to the real space and your field will be divergence-free.